# Trace norm sum of tensor products

Tags: normed-spaces, tensor-products

For two arbitrary matrices $A, B$, it is fulfilled

$\|A+B\|\leq\|A\|+\|B\|$,

where $\|\cdot\|$ is the trace norm.

Is the following satisfied:

$\|A\otimes1+1\otimes B\|=\|A\|+\|B\|$?

As from the comments of user8675309 the above equality is probably not true, what about the following:

$\|\frac{1}{d_2} A\otimes1+ \frac{1}{d_1}1\otimes B\|=\|A\|+\|B\|$,

where $d_1/d_2$ ist the dimension of respectively the first/second  Hilbert space.

Comment: Hm, could you explain it in more detail as an answer?

Comment: It is an identity matrix.

Comment: I have made some edits.

Comment: If you replace the trace norm with the sup norm (the standard norm), your first equality is satisfied for positive (hermitian) matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hoped for relation
$\big \Vert \frac{1}{d_2} A\otimes I+ \frac{1}{d_1}I\otimes B\big \Vert_{S_1}=\big \Vert A\big \Vert_{S_1} + \big \Vert B\big \Vert_{S_1}$
can't possibly true in general.  E.g. Set $A = I$ and $B:=-A$
then we have
$\big \Vert \frac{1}{d} I\otimes I+ \frac{1}{d}I\otimes (-I)\big \Vert_{S_1} = \big \Vert \frac{1}{d} I\otimes I- \frac{1}{d}I\otimes I\big \Vert_{S_1} =\big\Vert 0 \big\Vert_{S_1} = 0 \lt \big \Vert A\big \Vert_{S_1} + \big \Vert B\big \Vert_{S_1}$

where the RHS is $\gt 0$ by positive definiteness of the Schatten 1 norm (it *is* a norm afterall).

now in general we do have
$\big \Vert \big(\frac{1}{d_2} A\big)\oplus \big(\frac{1}{d_1}B\big)\big \Vert_{S_1}$
$=\big \Vert \frac{1}{d_2} A\otimes I_{d_2}+ \frac{1}{d_1}I_{d_1}\otimes B\big \Vert_{S_1}$
$\leq \big \Vert \frac{1}{d_2} A\otimes I_{d_2} \big \Vert_{S_1} +\big\Vert \frac{1}{d_1}I_{d_1}\otimes B\big \Vert_{S_1}$
$=\big \Vert A\big \Vert_{S_1} + \big \Vert B\big \Vert_{S_1}$

by application of triangle inequality.  The final equality comes from the fact that Kronecker Products of two matrices, $X \otimes Y$, has singular values given by $\sigma(X\otimes Y)= \sigma(X)\otimes \sigma(Y)$ (which appears to be a homomorphism)

Comment: In your example, why the equality cannot be in general true, B is a negative operator. What if both A and B are positive operators?

Comment: it should be somewhat immediate if both are Hermitian positive (semi)defintie since then $\big \Vert \frac{1}{d_2} A\otimes I_{d_2}+ \frac{1}{d_1}I_{d_1}\otimes B\big \Vert_{S_1}$ $= \text{trace}\big(\frac{1}{d_2} A\otimes I_{d_2}+ \frac{1}{d_1}I_{d_1}\otimes B\big)$ $= \text{trace}\big(\frac{1}{d_2} A\otimes I_{d_2}\big)+ \text{trace}\big(\frac{1}{d_1}I_{d_1}\otimes B\big)$ $=\big \Vert \frac{1}{d_2} A\otimes I_{d_2}\big \Vert_{S_1}+ \big \Vert\frac{1}{d_1}I_{d_1}\otimes B\big \Vert_{S_1}$